# If $8\sin x - \cos x=4$, then find possible values of $x$

Tags: trigonometry

I am not understanding what exactly can watch do here. First I thought that if I could square it but it was in vain. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: Use $8\sin(x)-4=\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ and you get a quadratic equation in $\sin(x)$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This is coming very complicated quadratic equation.

Comment: Since it is quadratic, you can solve it. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \sin(x) = \frac 1 2 + \frac {\cos(x)}{8}$

$ \sin^2(x) = (\frac 1 2 + \frac {\cos(x)}{8})^2$

$ 1 - \cos^2(x) = (\frac 1 2 + \frac {\cos(x)}{8})^2$

you can manage it now ? just a quadratic equation...

Comment: Squaring an equation may introduce fake solutions. And this is exacly what happens in this case!

Comment: you have to check..I agree... its the same when substituing $ \tan(\frac x 2) $ At least its a quadratic equation  it has max 2 solutions just need to check and eliminate the fake ones.

Answer (score 3):

Put $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$. Then $\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. The equation reduces to
$$3t^2 - 16t + 5 = 0$$ and hence $(3t-1)(t-5) = 0$. Hence the solutions are given by $\tan \frac{x}{2} = 5$ or $\frac{1}{3}$

Let us verify the solutions graphically. The following shows the graphs of $8 \sin(x) - \cos(x) = 5$ (green curve), $\tan \frac{x}{2} = 5$ (blue curve) and $\tan \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$ (red curve). It is clear that we have obtained all the solutions.
[image]

Comment: Did you at least verify your solutions?

Comment: @Raffaele I have updated the solution with a graphical verification. Hopefully, I have answered your query. Let me know if I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

$8\sin x -\cos x =4$

solve for $\cos x$

$\cos x = 8\sin x -4$

plug in the fundamental identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=1$

$\sin^2 x + \left ( 8\sin x -4\right)^2=1$

$65 \sin ^2 x -64 \sin x +15=0$

$\sin x = \dfrac{64\pm \sqrt{64^2-4\cdot 65 \cdot 15}}{130}$

$\sin x = \dfrac{3}{5} \to x = \arcsin \left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)+2k \pi \lor x=\pi-\arcsin \left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)+2k \pi$

$\sin x = \dfrac{5}{13} \to x = \arcsin \left(\dfrac{5}{13}\right)+2k \pi \lor x=\pi-\arcsin \left(\dfrac{5}{13}\right)+2k \pi$

Hope this helps

Comment: @dromastyx Are you kidding? I have deleted my silly wrong comment and even canceled my $-1$ to your answer: please let's behave like adults

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$a\sin x+ b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\arctan(b/a))$$
you can write it as
$$8\sin x-\cos x=\sqrt{8^2+(-1)^2}\sin(x+\arctan(-1/8))=4$$
that is
$$\sqrt{65}\sin(x-\arctan(1/8))=4
$$
$$x-\arctan(1/8)=\arcsin(\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}})+2\pi n \text{ or}$$
$$\pi-(x-\arctan(1/8))=\arcsin(\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}})+2\pi n$$
$$\iff \begin{cases}x=\arcsin(\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}})+\arctan(1/8)+2\pi n \\ x=-\arcsin(\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}})+\arctan(1/8)+\pi+2\pi n\end{cases}$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

A quick check with Mathematica yields:
$$\left\{\left\{x\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[2 \pi  c_1+\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{12}\right),c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[2 \pi  c_1+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right),c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right\}\right\}$$
which coincides with the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that if $f(x)=a\sin x + b\cos x$ and we define $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$  and $\alpha =\arctan \frac ba$ we have $$f(x)=r(\cos \alpha \sin x+\sin \alpha \cos x)=r\sin (x+\alpha)$$

Comment: Does this idea have something to do with phasors (rotating vectors)?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve $A \sin\theta + B \cos\theta = C$ is as follows.
Divide by $\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$.  Then, set $A / \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} = \sin\xi$
and $B / \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} = \cos\xi$.

This gives:

$$\sin\xi \sin\theta + \cos\xi \cos\theta = C / \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}.$$

So, the solution is given by

$$\cos(\theta - \xi) = C / \sqrt{A^2 + B^2},$$

where $\xi$ is the angle that the vector $(A,B)$ makes with the positive $x$ semi-axis.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your answer